# Does anybody know how to fix Do-Try-Catch error code= EXC_1386_INVOP in swift?

Tags: swift, error-handling

I'm writing calculator app in swift when I tried to add audio file I put this above the calc programming:

```
var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    player.play()
}
```

and down below in view did load I put this. Please, any help will be great!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    do
    {
        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "song", ofType: "mp4")
        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
    }
    catch
    {
        // error
        abort()
    }

}
```

Comment: Is auudioPath nil? If so, the mp4 file isn't actually in your app bundle.

Comment: Does `try player =` compile at all? By the way, why not `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "song", withExtension: "mp4")`?

Comment: audiopath does equal nil, but mp4 is my file type

Answer (score 0):

you are retreiving path Not the URL... secondly your do try Syntax is wrong... try this code

```
 do
{
    let audioPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "song", withExtension: "mp4")
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
}
catch
{
```